# RxJava zip 3 observables - onSubscribe lag

Tags: java, rx-java2

Please look at this simple code:

```
private void refreshData(String endpoint)
    {
        KProgressHUD busy = Utils.showBusyIndicator(MainActivity.this);
        MCityEndpoint mcityService = ServiceFactory.createRetrofitService(MCityEndpoint.class, Configuration.getApiUrl());

        Disposable disposable = Observable.zip
                (
                        mcityService.getMcityDictionaries(selectedCity.id),
                        mcityService.getEvents(selectedCity.id, endpoint),
                        mcityService.getUserDetails(selectedCity.id),

                        (dictionaries,events, userInfo) ->
                        {
                            processData(dictionaries, events, userInfo);

                            return  events.events;
                        }

                )
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(result ->
                {
                    if(mFragment instanceof ListFragment)
                    {
                        ((ListFragment) mFragment).refreshData(result);
                    }

                    updateUserDetails();
                    busy.dismiss();

                    Log.d(Configuration.tag,"Refresh data complete");

                }, throwable ->
                {
                    Log.d(Configuration.tag,throwable.toString());
                    busy.dismiss();
                    this.logout(true);

                });


        mCompositeDisposable.add(disposable);
    }
```

I want to call 3 observables, process their values and finally load data to list. It works, but I'm getting 1 second lag. Result is:

- Busy indicator shows up
- Busy indicator hides
- **1 second lag** without busy indicator visible
- List is refreshed after lag

I can't understand reason of lag in this case. Everything should be refreshed with busy indicator visible. Do you have any idea?

Comment: The given code looks fine. Can you include `updateUserDetails()` implementation?

Comment: Ok, I know what's wrong. Indeed RxJava calls are fine. Problem is in `refreshData` method, list refreshing causes lag.